# Why isn't Sabu returning back to Jupiter?

Tags: chacha-chaudhary, diamond-comics

In *Chacha Chaudhary* comics, Sabu has a working spaceship with which he came to Earth. This was displayed in some of the issues.

Why is he not returning to his home?

Comment: `May be because he feels like a family on earth with chacha.

Answer (score 1):

In the Earth, He met Chacha Chaudhary and feels like a family. Here Chacha helped him when he landed on the Earth and give him the required assistance and love which he wants. So, this might be a reason that he hadn't decided to go back to Jupiter.